# Compare consecutive rows in csv in python version 3.1.3

Tags: python, csv, rows

New to scripting and writing a script to log into network devices and check certain info.

I have a csv file with two columns, first column is ip address,second is what i want to check.  Sometimes, same ip address occurs in multiple consecutive rows.  How can i set the script to check the next row and if its same ip to not log out?

I tried the next() method but that just skipped the next line if its same as previous.

Comment: could you post what you have?

Answer (score 1):

```
prevIP = ''
for line in data:
    if line[0] == prevIP:
        continue
    prevIP = line[0]
    print line[1]
```

Assuming you're in a loop.

Comment: I'm using csv.reader, so line[x] wont work right? It gives invalid syntax. Thanks.

Comment: You're using python3+, so change the `print line[1]` to `print(line[1])` The rest should work

Comment: Great, still have remnants of python 2 floating around in my brain.

Answer (score 0):

Another general idea (from python 2) ...

```
IPS = [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('c', 1), ('c', 2), ('c', 3)]

def login(ip):
    print "Logging in to ip ...", ip

def logout():
    print "Logging out" 

previous_ip = IPS[0][0]
login(IPS[0][0])

for ip, num in IPS:
    if ip <> previous_ip:
        logout()
        login(ip)

    print "*** Now checking ...", ip, num
    previous_ip = ip

logout()
```